# Accessing Map elements in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, key-value

I've got a Map with data type

```
Map<String, Map<String, Key?>> filterOption
```

and it has some data

```
 Map<String, Map<String, Key?>> filterOption={"Certificate Provider":{"nvq":GlobalKey()},"Course Language":{"nvq":GlobalKey()},"Course Amount":{"nvq":GlobalKey()},"Duration":{"nvq":GlobalKey()},"Category":{"nvq":GlobalKey()}};
```

How can I access the Key?(Global key value) of each individual entry ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the subscript access operator `[]` on `filterOption` with one of the keys for your outer map. Since, subscripting a map returns a nullable type you can then use the [conditional subscript access operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators) `?[]` with `'nvq'` to then get the `GlobalKey` from the inner map.

```dart
Key? key = filterOption['Certificate Provider']?['nvq'];
```